# DIY Powerline adapters - can they be made?

Tags: networking, ethernet, computer-building, powerline-networking

Given the cost of existing powerline adapters, I am curious as to how complex they really are, could they be made from a selection of components and some knowledge?

Do they absolutely require propitiatory software or could the most fundamental elements be recreated?

For the sake of the question, please assume I want to create a powerline adapter that does not feature any kind of encryption between adapters, or indication lights; it would purely be the cheapest and most basic functional design.

How would one go about this?

Comment: Thy don't require any also create but the engineering knowledge is a lot if you are asking this question, means, you don't have it

Comment: Keep in mind that most commercial electronic products are mass-produced.  The components are purchased in vast quantities and the creation is highly automated.  The prototypes might be made by hand, but rarely the actual product.  Even if you had the design, tools, parts, skills, and time to make one yourself,  the parts, alone, would cost you more than buying it off-the-shelf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, EoP uses mains voltage which is severely dangerous, do not attempt anything unless you're sure its safe.

The current popular standard is AV2, that means you need to create an OFDM modem that can withstand 110/230V AC. Then you need a gigabit interface and a board to interface the two.

Building such a device would require a high level of expertise and would be huge without the use of printed ICs. AV2 sets can be purchased for as low as £30 now, this is very cheap for what you get.

Comment: I see, thank you for the advice - no messing with the mains for me without expert help!